# is there any way to sort a SObject list

Tags: apex

I have a requirement, where I have to sort a SObject list by one field.

```
List<Account> initAccountList;

Private void loadPricingMap () {

    if(initAccountList== null) {
       initAccountList= [select Id,
                                End_Date__c,
                                Product__c,
                                Effective_Date__c
                                from Account
                                order by Effective_Date__c];
        }
        else if(!initAccountList.isEmpty()) {
            // TO DO : Use SObjectComparable to sort initAccountListby effective date
        }

}
```

Comment: The Salesforce List class has an method for Sorting as you can see in this documentation article: https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_list_sorting_sobject.htm is that of any use?

Comment: If you want to specify the specific field you want to sort on, scroll down to the "using comparable" bit of the doc.

Answer (score 4):

I wrote a [utility class](https://github.com/ChuckJonas/apex-sort-sobs) to help with sorting SObjects lists.  It supports traversal of multiple parents.

Sort on Field:

```
Account[] accs = [SELECT My_Custom_Field__c FROM Account LIMIT 2000];
SortSobs.ascending(accs, Account.My_Custom_Field__c);
```

Sort on parent(s) field:

```
List<Contact> entries = [SELECT Name, Account.Name FROM Contact limit 2000];
SortSobs.ascending(entries, SObjectField[]{ Contact.Account, Account.Name });
```

If performance is critical, I would be careful using this (ex: in triggers on core objects).

Answer (score 3):

You can sort using SOQL, that is definitely the easiest but if necessary you can sort a list already in memory. This entails creating a separate wrapper class of your object that implements the [comparable interface](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_list_sorting_sobject.htm).

Comment: You are correct, SOQl is the easy way to sort a list. I did this, as you can see above.
I have seen this document. But I am not clear with the example given in the doc.

`OpportunityWrapper` is a custom class, which has `CompareTo()` method. 

But here we are having a list of `Account` . So how we will implement that example here?

Comment: You will have to create a separate class that is an account wrapper to use the comparable interface and compareTo() method.